# How to print next N lines for all instances of a string pattern?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, parsing

I have a file which looks like the following:

**File**

```
variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25
10076   0.84
10101   1
10126   1
10151   1
10176   1
10201   1
10226   1.72
variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25
10251   2
10276   1.16
10301   1
10326   1
10351   1
10376   1
10401   1
10426   0.28
11451   0.04
variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25
9781451     2
19781476    2
19781501    2
19781526    2
19781551    1
19781576    1
19781601    0.48
variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25
19781826    0.28
19781851    1
19781876    1
19781901    1
19781926    1
19781951    1.48
19781976    3.68
19782001    4.56
19782026    4
variableStep chrom=chr3 span=25
4813476 1
24813501    1
24813526    1
24813551    1
24813576    1.88
24813601    2
variableStep chrom=chr3 span=25
24813626    1.4
24813651    1.48
24813676    2
24813701    2
24813726    2
24813751    2
variableStep chrom=chr4 span=25
24815401    2.24
24815426    3
24815451    3
24815476    3
24815501    3
24815526    2.04
variableStep chrom=chr4 span=25
24815551    2
24815576    1.76
24815601    0.76
24815951    0.48
24815976    1
24816001    1
24816026    1
24816051    1
variableStep chrom=chr5 span=25
24817226    0.92
24817251    1.48
24817276    3
24817301    3
variableStep chrom=chr5 span=25
24817326    3
24817351    3
24817376    3
24817401    3.04
24817426    3.08
```

**What Is Needed**

What I need to do is, for all instances of say `variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25`, print out the subsequent `n` lines to an output file. `n` I must mention, is highly variable. It can vary anywhere from 300,000 to 500,000+ in the actual file.

**Desired Output**

1.Output_file_1_for_variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25

```
10076   0.84
10101   1
10126   1
10151   1
10176   1
10201   1
10226   1.72
10251   2
10276   1.16
10301   1
10326   1
10351   1
10376   1
10401   1
10426   0.28
11451   0.04
```

2._Output_file_2_for_variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25

```
9781451     2
19781476    2
19781501    2
19781526    2
19781551    1
19781576    1
19781601    0.48
19781826    0.28
19781851    1
19781876    1
19781901    1
19781926    1
19781951    1.48
19781976    3.68
19782001    4.56
19782026    4
```

3._Output_file_3_for_variableStep chrom=chr3 span=25

```
4813476     1
24813501    1
24813526    1
24813551    1
24813576    1.88
24813601    2
24813626    1.4
24813651    1.48
24813676    2
24813701    2
24813726    2
24813751    2
```

4._Output_file_4_for_variableStep chrom=chr4 span=25

```
24815401    2.24
24815426    3
24815451    3
24815476    3
24815501    3
24815526    2.04
24815551    2
24815576    1.76
24815601    0.76
24815951    0.48
24815976    1
24816001    1
24816026    1
24816051    1
```

5._Output_file_5_for_variableStep chrom=chr5 span=25

```
24817226    0.92
24817251    1.48
24817276    3
24817301    3
24817326    3
24817351    3
24817376    3
24817401    3.04
24817426    3.08
```

**Background**
I still consider myself a Perl newbie so the code I've written doesn't quite completely accomplish the task.

In fact the following code depicts the 3 ways in which I was trying to get it to work. For the code with pattern `variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25` I tried to print the subsequent lines after the regex match manually.

From that I figured, I need a loop to run through all the subsequent lines,which is what i've written with the pattern `variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25`. But then, I realized I need an exit mechanism as otherwise all the subsequent lines were getting printed.

It is `this exit pattern` written as `last if /^v.*$/`which I need to figure out. As the one I have is currently printing only the very `first` instance of the specific pattern. There is no blank line either on which I could exit. Had I had a blank line, this piece of code is working perfectly fine( modifying to `last if /^$/` ). I even tried using a non decimal character as `/^\D.*$/`, but it isn't working. `What exit pattern should I use?`

The remaining part of the code was my baby attempts to get the program to work and it only prints the single subsequent line after the pattern match.

**Code**

```
#Trial code to parse main file
use 5.014;
use warnings;

#Assign filename
my $file = 'trial.txt';

#Open filename
open my $fh, '<' , $file || die $!;

#Open output
open OUT1, ">Trial_chr1.out" || die $!;
open OUT2, ">Trial_chr2.out" || die $!;
open OUT3, ">Trial_chr3.out" || die $!;
open OUT4, ">Trial_chr4.out" || die $!;
open out5, ">Trial_chr5.out" || die $!;

#Read in file
while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    if (/^variableStep chrom=chr1 span=25/){

        my $nextline1 = <$fh>;#means next line after pattern match
        my $nextline2 = <$fh>;
        my $nextline3 = <$fh>;
        my $nextline4 = <$fh>;
        my $nextline5 = <$fh>;
        my $nextline6 = <$fh>;
        my $nextline7 = <$fh>;
        print OUT1 $nextline1;
        print OUT1 $nextline2;
        print OUT1 $nextline3;
        print OUT1 $nextline4;
        print OUT1 $nextline5;
        print OUT1 $nextline6;
        print OUT1 $nextline7;

    }elsif(/^variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25/){

        my @grabbed_lines; #Initialize array to store lines after pattern match
        while (<$fh>){ #Read subsequent lines while in a loop

        last if /^v.*$/; #Break out of the loop if line encountered begins with v
        push @grabbed_lines, $_;# As long as the above condition is false, push the lines into the array

        }print OUT2 @grabbed_lines; # Print the grabbed lines

    }elsif(/^variableStep chrom=chr3 span=25/){
        my $nextline = <$fh>;
        print OUT3 $nextline;

    }elsif(/^variableStep chrom=chr4 span=25/){
        my $nextline = <$fh>;
        print OUT4 $nextline;
    }elsif(/^variableStep chrom=chr5 span=25/){
        my $nextline = <$fh>;
        print out5 $nextline;
    }
}


#Exit
exit;
```

Thank you for taking the time to go through my question. I'd be grateful for any tips and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I missunderstood the `n` part, it is different for each match, this is tested and working:

```
my $found = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( $found && /^\d/ ) {
        print $_;
    }
    else {
        $found = 0;
    }

    if (/^variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25/) {
        $found = 1;
    }
}
```

this way it prints all following rows that start with a digit.

**Explanation:**

The problem here is, that each time you are calling `<$fh>` it reads the next row, so if you test the row content and your test fails, you should not do the next loop, because then the next row is read and you lost the row where the test failed.

So I came to this solution:

1. I use a flag to know in which mode I am, am I searching for rows to print or not?
2. The first `if` is only entered

   1. if I have been in the second if if in a loop before and the flag has been set to "1"
   2. AND the row start with a digit.
3. When this test fails, i.e. there is no row with a digit at the beginning, I reset the flag and have then the chance to look again at the same row if it starts with "variableStep ..."

Comment: `N` unfortunately is highly variable :(  Perhaps I should edit my question to highlight this aspect. In a subset of the actual file which is ~1GB big, n is anywhere from 300,000-500,000 for the few patterns I tried going through.

Comment: @Neal, sorry I missunderstood that part, I changed my answer, it is untested, but should work something like this.

Comment: @Neal, I changed my solution once more, this time it is tested and running.

Comment: Hey this works really great. If I understand the overall logic correctly, you are using a `flag variable` I think? Broadly I think the value of `$found` is set to 0(false) and when the pattern match is found, the value changes to 1(true) and subsequent digits are printed?  Would you be able to perhaps explain the logic and control flow line wise as I cannot figure out why `if (/^variableStep chrom=chr2 span=25/)` must be written afterwards.. :(

Comment: @Neal, I added an Explanation. I am not sure, but I think you can change the order of the two ifs, have no time at the moment to test it.

Comment: Many many thanks for the explanation stema :) It's a very innovative way to look at things! And I have indeed checked and the order of the two `if` statements cannot be changed. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner below should do the trick (assuming that output files doesn't already exist):

```
perl -lne '/variableStep/ && open($fh, ">>", $_) && next; print $fh $_;' input.txt
```

--

btw: `||` operator has high priority (`man perlop`), so command:

```
open OUT1, ">Trial_chr1.out" || die $!;
```

is understood by perl as

```
open OUT1, (">Trial_chr1.out" || die $!);
```

To do error checking you should use `and` operator instead or use parentheses to enforce desired behaviour

Comment: Hello otokan! Thanks for your answer. This is a very novel way for me to get things done. Where may I read more about command line one-liners? Also, unfortunately, I am getting this cryptic error while typing the above command in the cmd terminal. `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line1`. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hello otokan! One small question, does this work only for UNIX systems? Because I typed the command in UNIX and it works perfectly fine ...well not the exact , the simplest one liner `perl -e 'print "hello world\n"'`. The same command produces error in Windows cmd terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I love [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), but [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is more suitable in this case, see :

```
$ awk '
    {if ($0 ~ /^variableStep/) {file="output_file_"++c"_"$1"_"$2"_"$3}
    else{print $0 > file}}
' file.txt

$ ls -l output_file_*
```

Comment: Hello many thanks for your kind answer. However, I am still learning the ropes of Perl ...and haven't even touched awk :( Perhaps one day, I would get the opportunity to look into awk too

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and `File::Slurp` useful module :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my ($c, $file);

while (<>) {
    if (/^variableStep\s+chrom=\w+\s+span=\d+/) {
        $c++;
        $file = $&;
        $file =~ s/\s/_/g;
        $file = "output_file_${c}_" . $file;
    }
    else {
        append_file $file, $_;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
$ perl ./script.pl file.txt
$ ls -l output_file_*
```

Comment: Have you tested this one Neal ?